# How to get position of table row identified by attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

While trying to find solution for my problem I have noticed that most problems concerns only how to get table identified by id which can be done via:

```
document.getElementById("#tableID")
```

but my table is not so clean as it is in tutorials.
My problem is I want to create function such as:

```
function scrollToUser(user_id){ 
 xxxx?;
}
```

having table as below:

```
<div id="users">
    <table class="data table table-striped" width="100%" style="" id="table0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="js--entity-list__header entity-list__header">
                    <span class="columnsSettings">&nbsp;</span>
                    <span class="sorter entity-list__header--fakelink js--orderAsc" order="1">Username <span class="js--orderIcon fa fa-chevron-up">
                    </span>
                </span>
            </th>
            <th class="js--entity-list__header entity-list__header">Source</th>
            <th class="js--entity-list__header entity-list__header">
                <span class="sorter entity-list__header--fakelink " order="2">Surname, First name <span class="js--orderIcon fa ">
                </span>
            </th>
            <th class="js--entity-list__header entity-list__header">Cost center</th>
            <th class="js--entity-list__header entity-list__header">Email</th>
            <th class="js--entity-list__header entity-list__header entity-list__header--icon">&nbsp;</th>
            <th class="js--entity-list__header entity-list__header entity-list__header--icon">&nbsp;</th>
            <th class="js--entity-list__header entity-list__header entity-list__header--icon">&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="js--entity-list__row " item="id17">
            <td class=" firstcell  ">admin</td>
            <td class=" ">Internal</td>
            <td class=" breakable">Administrator, System</td>
            <td class=" ">0</td>
            <td class=" "></td>
            <td class=" entity-list__icon-column ">
                <span class="">
                </span>
            </td>
            <td class=" entity-list__icon-column ">
                <span class="ico_user_edit icon fa fa-wrench" tooltip="0">
                </span>
            </td>
            <td class=" entity-list__icon-column ">
                <span class="">
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="js--entity-list__row " item="id28">
            <td class=" firstcell  ">login_0</td>
            <td class=" ">Internal</td>
            <td class=" breakable">surname_0, name_0</td>
            <td class=" ">10</td>
            <td class=" ">email_0</td>
            <td class=" entity-list__icon-column ">
                <span class="ico_role_access icon fa fa-credit-card" tooltip="1">
                </span>
            </td>
            <td class=" entity-list__icon-column ">
                <span class="ico_user_edit icon fa fa-wrench" tooltip="2">
                </span>
            </td>
            <td class=" entity-list__icon-column ">
                <span class="ico_user_delete icon fa fa-trash" tooltip="3">
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="js--entity-list__row " item="id29">
            <td class=" firstcell  ">login_1</td>
            <td class=" ">Internal</td>
            <td class=" breakable">surname_1, name_1</td>
            <td class=" ">10</td>
            <td class=" ">email_1</td>
            <td class=" entity-list__icon-column ">
                <span class="ico_role_access icon fa fa-credit-card" tooltip="4">
                </span>
            </td>
            <td class=" entity-list__icon-column ">
                <span class="ico_user_edit icon fa fa-wrench" tooltip="5">
                </span>
            </td>
            <td class=" entity-list__icon-column ">
                <span class="ico_user_delete icon fa fa-trash" tooltip="6">
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

so the identifier is item="id28" - attribute with value id28

```
<tr class="js--entity-list__row " item="id28">
```

so I would like to call function:

```
scrollToUser(28);
```

All things which I have tried so far was unsuccessfull, here are the list of thing for which I have played around:

```
var rows = $("#users,table,tbody")[2].rows;
for(item in rows){console.log(item.innerText);}
$(rows[0]).attr("item"); // here I got position but how to search it instead of hardcoding [0]
$("#users,table,tbody > tr:eq(admin)").position();
var x = $("#users,table,tbody");
$([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({ scrollTop: $(document.getElementById("table0").rows[1]).offset().top }, 2000);
```

Most annoying thing is that when I get some thing like row[2] and the type of everything here is object so I dont know what specific functions I can call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try :

```
function scrollToUser(user_id){
  var itemId = "id" + user_id;
  document.querySelector("[item='" + itemId + "']").scrollIntoView({
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}
```